# Accessing multi-dimensional array object created with simplexml_load_file in PHP returns null?

Tags: php, arrays, object, rss, simplexml

I have a RSS object `$rssObject` created using the PHP `simplexml_load_file` function, the goal is to get the value of `[href]`.

`var_dump($rssObject)` returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => https://www.example.com
                                )

                        )
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to get the contents of `[href]` using this notation which returns `null`

```
$rssObject[0]->link[0]->{'@attributes'}['href'];
```

Why is this?

Comment: Why has this been down-voted? Please see answer, it justified this question when the var_dump is outputting a misleading output!

Comment: Yeah, this is a very common confusion, and we should really have a canonical answer explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SimpleXML, attributes are accessed using array notation:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file();
$url = $xml[0]->link[0]['href'];
```

See "[Example #5 Using attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6348)" in the PHP manual.

Comment: Hi can you explain why I don't have to use [@attributes] as a key?

Comment: The `var_dump` representation you see is .. a lie. SimpleXML does some magic, and you have to adhere to its rules.